# Reference not working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#

I have a simple console application that is supposed to use *Newtonsoft.Json* to desrialize JSON objects.
I installed Newtonsoft.Json via **Manage Nuget for Solution** and the package shows as installed in Nuget however the reference is not showing at all in the project or in the file **.csproj**.

Any clue?

Comment: How many projects in your solution?  Did you add it to the right one?

Comment: Only one project. I keep installing newtonsoft.json but it is not showing in the references.

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting? (normally that won't matter as many NuGet packages include versions for multiple .NET versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should add a reference to the library. Project->Add reference, find package you need and press ok. Then you can include this package to your project with keyword **using**.

Comment: OP is using _NuGet_.  With NuGet there is no need for a manual **Add Reference**

Comment: @Roy *except* if the automatic reference addition performed by NuGet failed for some reason. In this case it's reasonable to add it manually (pointing at the lib in the `packages` dir).

Comment: @Pavel, where will I find the package I want to include. I don't know where it is saved on my machine.

Comment: @UbuntuDude You don't have to find this package. Just search the name of your package in __Add reference__ window.

Comment: @Pavel. Under what Tab? I can't find it.

Comment: @UbuntuDude If you can't find it so there is no such a library I think.

Comment: I created a new project and I was able to install Newtonsoft.Json using Mange Nuget for Solution without any problem. This made me think that there is something wrong with the other project. I compared all the properties of the two projects to make sure they target the same .NET framework, use the same CPU, etc. but still no joy. When I try to install Newtonsoft .Json on the existing project it just won't install. Do you have any clue?

Comment: I managed to install Json reference. I uninstalled it and re-installed it using the NuGet command line and it is now working. Thank you for you r help.